# Opening window/dialog from .Net Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have created a C# .Net windows service. There are some configuration files which are being used by this service. Right now we have another dll component which is being loaded by an application and from there we create the configuration files. I want to open this dll component from my directly service. Following the option that I want to provide in final service exe which will act as service as well as configurator.

Lets say exe name is SampleServ.exe then options should be:

1. With out any arguments it should start as service
2. With argument like SampleServ.exe -config (it should start configurator instead of service)

I am trying like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
           new Service1() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

    }
    else
    {
        MainPage wnd = new MainPage();
        wnd.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Here MainPage is derived Window, and i am not able to add namespace system.window because of service limitation.

Please let me know if other way is possible.

---

After adding some more component in project reference I am able to do this. I have added reference like "PresentationCore", "PresentatinoFramework", "System.Xaml". I just wanted to know if **any implication of adding such component.? Any idea?**

Otherwise now my code is working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here is a complete example of what you need, it also include a install/uninstall feature

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/kim/archive/2009/01/04/self-installing-windows-service.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` to get the arguments (index 0 is the name of the program, though, be careful). If argument 1 is not "-config", start as a service, otherwise show your configuration form.

Comment: I am able to get argument. That is not my problem. When I am creating object of component (which is wondow) and doing .ShowDialog, that now happeing. It is not allowing me to add form related namespace / dependencies.